# Multiple Flip Flop device

Tags: vhdl, flip-flop

I'm trying to write a VHDL code that represents an image diagram. I'm new to VHDL so I used a lot of conditionals for it to work. However, I'm having problems with the preset and clear inputs, I used `if` and `elsif` in order to know which one preset or clear is working, but I keep receiving this error:

`Asynchronous Preset equation not allowed error for Q`

My code is:

```vhdl
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FF is
    port(
            clk: in std_logic;
            ctrl : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            R,S,D,J,K,T,PS,CL: in std_logic;
            Q,QN : out std_logic);
    end FF;
    
architecture FF_arq of FF is
     signal tmp:std_logic;
 begin
    process(clk,ctrl,PS,CL)
        begin
            if PS='0' then
                tmp<='1';
            elsif CL='0' then
                tmp<='0';
            elsif (rising_edge(clk))then
                if ctrl="00" then
                    if R='0' and S='0' then
                        tmp<=tmp;
                    else if R='1' and S='0' then
                        tmp<='0';
                    else if R='0' and S='1' then
                        tmp<='1';
                    else
                        tmp<='-';
                    end if;
                    end if;
                    end if;
                else if ctrl="01" then
                    if D='0' then
                        tmp<='0';
                    else if D='1' then
                        tmp<='1';
                    else
                        tmp<='-';
                    end if;
                    end if;
                else if ctrl="10" then
                    if J='0' and K='0'then
                        tmp<=tmp;
                    else if J='1' and K='1' then
                        tmp<= not tmp;
                    else if J='1' and K='0' then
                        tmp<='1';
                    else
                        tmp<='0';
                    end if;
                    end if;
                    end if;
                else
                    if T='0' then
                        tmp<=tmp;
                    else 
                        tmp<= not tmp;
                    end if;
                end if;
                end if;
                end if;
            end if;                 
    end process;
    Q<= tmp;
    QN<= not tmp;
end FF_arq;
```

This is the diagram:

[image]

Comment: The error message appears to be from OrCAD. There's no indication of who's target device but you'll find no FPGA vendor is offering a flip flop with both preset and reset today, a behavior shared by a lot of PLD devices as well. You're missing some information in your question telling your readers what you were doing and what's complaining. You could always model the flip flop as a gate level master slave flip flop using ctrl to control the master stage inputs.

Comment: (Oh, and `else if` can be replaced by `elsif` to conserve `end if`s.)

Comment: You haven't explicitly provided a question and there are still details missing explaining what the error means to what tool.

Answer (score 0):

Tryed to short some things up, maybe there are some better solutions.

```vhdl
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FF is
    port(
            clk: in std_logic;
            ctrl : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            R,S,D,J,K,T,PS,CL: in std_logic;
            Q,QN : out std_logic);
    end FF;
    
architecture FF_arq of FF is
    signal tmp : std_logic := '0';
    signal RS : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal JK : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
 begin
 
    Q <= tmp;
    QN <= not(tmp);
 
    process(clk,PS,CL)
        begin
            if PS='0' then
                tmp<='1';
            elsif CL='0' then
                tmp<='0';
            elsif (rising_edge(clk))then
            
                RS(1) <= R;
                RS(0) <= S;
                JK(1) <= J;
                JK(0) <= K;
            
                case ctrl is
                    when "00" => case RS is
                                    when "00" => tmp <= tmp;
                                    when "10" => tmp <= '0';
                                    when "01" => tmp <= '1';
                                    when others => tmp <= '-';
                                 end case;
                    when "01" => tmp <= D;
                    when "10" => case JK is
                                    when "00" => tmp <= tmp;
                                    when "11" => tmp <= not(tmp);
                                    when "10" => tmp <= '1';
                                    when others => tmp <= '0';
                                 end case;
                    when others =>  if T='0' then
                                        tmp <= tmp;
                                    else
                                        tmp <= not(tmp);
                                    end if;
                end case;
            end if;                 
    end process;
end FF_arq;
```

> @ the moment i can´t check the code, so maybe there are some unwanted features...